# pdo php query not showing anything for debug

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

```
print_r($con->_con);
echo "(SELECT * FROM fvwItems WHERE itemname LIKE :key)";
echo "\PDO::errorInfo():\n";
print_r($con->_con->errorInfo());// no error showing
$stmt = $con->_con->prepare("(SELECT * FROM fvwItems WHERE itemname LIKE :key)", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
echo $stmt;//not putting any output
echo "\PDO::errorInfo():\n";
print_r($con->_con->errorInfo());
```

I have the query above and I only get

```
Resource id #10
(SELECT * FROM fvwItems WHERE itemname LIKE :key)\PDO::errorInfo():
```

In the dev tools of chrome. I also have the query inside `try/catch` but I dont what error or what is the problem in my query because it is not giving me enough information to tell which is having problem.

Anything beyond the `$stmt = $con->_con->prepare("(SELECT * FROM fvwItems WHERE itemname LIKE :key)", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));` is not shown either error or not

What could be the best way to check what is wrong with the query?

`UPDATE`

My connection is like this:

```
$connectionOptions = array(
            "Database" => DB_NAME,
            "Uid" => DB_USER,
            "PWD" => DB_PASS
        );
        //Establishes the connection
        $this->_connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
```

I was thinking I need it to be `new PDO` so that it will run?

Like

```
$this->_connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=".DB_NAME.";",DB_USER,DB_PASS);
print_r($this->_connection);
```

Resulting in

```
PDO Object
(
)
```

But this is not connecting and it is getting error

Comment: You don't tell us what `$con->_con` is, does it actually have a `prepare()` method? Have you configured PHP to [show useful error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1255289)?

Answer (score -1):

After creation PDO object set this option:

```
$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```